# I can not passing data by vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am new in vue.js..
I use webpack + vue-cli .

But I can't pass the data from parent to child

code like this..

```js
   <template lang="html">
  <div>
    <input v-model="parentMsg"></input>
    <br>
    <child v-bind:msg="parentMsg"></child>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import child from './components/lists'
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      parentMsg: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {},
  ready: function () {},
  attached: function () {},
  methods: {},
  components: {
    child
  }
}
</script>
```

```js
<template>
  <div>
    {{msg}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      msg: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

By the way ...
How to bind child components to the parent array..

```
parent: data: array[...],
I want to bind the first of children's data to arr[0]
second to array[1]..
```

Is this possible?? or use v-for??

Comment: the code above is not work..I change the input in parent .. child isn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your child component use the `props` property to receive parent data like:

```
<script>
export default {
  props: ['msg'],
  data: function () {
    return {

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Read more about this [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Props)